# Use values from HashMap only with right key

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, hashmap

I`m trying to create a list of ImageViews with small images and to show big by clicking on them. I use parser in AsyncTask to download from site.

At first step ("doInBackground") parser read urls from small images and put them to  `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. I use key "imgUrlSmall"

Then read urls from big images and put to the same ArrayList. Use key "imgUrlBig"

In "onPostExecute" it creates the ImageViews and set the images `imageViewArray[i].setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(text));`

Then it set the ClickListener, On click by image it start new activity and put there the url of big image.

Now program show all images (big and small). How put to imageViewArray only values with key "imgUrlSmall". and putExtra with right value?

Maybe is some verification, like if `map.containsKey?`

For second part, to make putExtra maybe put all values with key "imgUrlBig" to standart `ArrayList<String>` and then by click on image use `v.getId()`?

Sorry for my English

Here the all code:

doInBackground

```
 protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imgItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                /* --First Parser-- */
                 HtmlCleaner htmlCleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
                 URL url = new URL(BLOG_URL);
                 TagNode root = htmlCleaner.clean(url);
                 Object[] statsNode3 = root.evaluateXPath(XPATH_STATS3);

                for (Object tag : statsNode3){
                        TagNode aTag = (TagNode) tag;
                        String href = aTag.getAttributeByName("src").trim();

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put("imgUrlSmall", href);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        imgItems.add(map);
                 }
                /* --Second Parser-- */
                 HtmlCleaner htmlCleaner2 = new HtmlCleaner();
                 URL url2 = new URL(BLOG_URL);
                 TagNode root2 = htmlCleaner2.clean(url2);

                 Object[] statsNode_Full_Image = root2.evaluateXPath(XPATH_STATS4);
                 for (Object tag : statsNode_Full_Image){
                        TagNode aTag = (TagNode) tag;
                        String href = aTag.getAttributeByName("href").trim();

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put("imgUrlBig", href);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        imgItems.add(map);
                        }

        return imgItems;

     }
```

onPostExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imgItems) {
String text="";
int i=0;    
 ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[imgItems.size()];
    for (HashMap<String, String> map : imgItems)
         for (Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet())
            {
                text = mapEntry.getValue();
                // create ImageView
                imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(Test4.this);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
                imageViewArray[i].setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(text));
                imageViewArray[i].setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            System.out.println(v.getId());
                            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Full_Image_Activity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("imgUrlBig", url); //Here i don`t know how to put the url
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                        }
                    });

                // Let's get the root layout and add our ImageView
                RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.moreImages);
                layout.addView(imageViewArray[i], params);
                i++;
                }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class with both urls and then you could use `ArrayList<HashMap<String, YourImageClass>>`
 class should be something like this

```
public class YourImageClass{
public String smallImageUrl;
public String bigImageUrl;
public String someNameOfImageMaybe;
etc.
}
```